# What is the disadvantage of viewing a report from iframe insted of using reportViewer control?

Tags: iframe, reporting-services

I have to show a report in a aspx page. So I find how to show a report from report server in asp page. Most of them are using reportViewer control, however, I am find that the iframe work fine to view report.

Does anyone know why they don't use iframe to view reports?

iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://{server}/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?{mypath}" id="frame" runat="server" width="1500" height="800">input URL is invalid </iframe>
```

reportViewer control:

```
     <rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="MyReportViewer" Width="100%" Height="700px"></rsweb:ReportViewer>

//C#

     MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                    ServerReport serverReport = MyReportViewer.ServerReport;
                    // Set the report server URL and report path
                    serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://{server}/ReportServer");
                    serverReport.ReportPath = "/{myPath}";
```

Comment: Users can view the report path, harder to add css.

Comment: @Snowlockk but they can not edit, update anything to my DB, right? if so, what is the problem regarding they viewing the report path (they can't see if they have no right), harder or adding css?

Comment: Depends on how your system is set up. If there is are variables in your report path string they could edit them to view other peoples data.

Comment: Can you still export to Excel?

Comment: Is it possible to add a drillthrough report in iframe?

Answer (score 0):

If the iFrame approach works for you - then it is likely to be the easiest for you. The report viewer control is useful if you need finer control over when to load reports, want to load local reports without a server or need to use different credentials for connecting to a report server.